# One click (or easy) way to Root Motorola Droid X with Morotola update 4.5.621

Tags: rooting, motorola-droid-x

I [read](http://www.droid-life.com/2012/03/19/droid-x-621-build-root-method-released-talk-about-device-trickery/) that the new  DROID X  build 4.5.621 prevents the most common Rooting methods.
There is a more [complicated method](http://rootzwiki.com/topic/19318-important-information-regarding-621-system-update/page__st__100__p__557044#entry557044) but I'm hoping there is a one-click method (less chance of me screwing up and bricking my Droid)

I have Android v 2.3.4.